# How do you use TinyMCE in ASP.NET Boilerplate?

Tags: ckeditor, tinymce, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using ABP 2.1.2 with the AdminBSB theme. I see the theme incorporates both TinyMCE and CKEditor, either of which I want to use in a form.

Have these been created as Angular modules in ABP or must I create them myself? If they are already supported, how do I use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ABP doesn't have implementation of those Angular modules. You have to create yourself.